# I have error in my VBA code for check and move cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MoveCells()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim columnToCheck As Integer
    columnToCheck = 12 ' change to the column number you want to check
    
    Do While WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L:L"), "<>8") > 0 ' keep looping until there are no more values in column L that are more than 8 characters
        For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("L2:L" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                If Len(cell.Value) <> 8 Then
                    For i = 1 To 147
                        cell.Offset(0, i - 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, i).Value
                        cell.Offset(0, i).ClearContents
                    Next i
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    Loop
End Sub
```

I assume error in "<>8" but I dont know how to resolve it, I used the code for search cell value not equal to 8 in column 12 and move left another cell form right to the column 12 ++ looping until there are no more values in column L or 12 not equal to 8

[image]

I used the code for search cell value not equal to 8 in column 12 and move left another cell form right to the column 12 ++ looping until there are no more values in column L or 12 not equal to 8

Comment: In which line of the code do you get this error?

Comment: So every row starting in Col M has an 8-character value which you want to shift left to Column M?  It would really help here to show a small "before" and "after" screenshot of what your code is intended to do.

Comment: no error line but when running on cell i got the error above

Comment: i assume error in <>8 or line for i 1 to 147, i think got the error when value cell in column 147 empty

Comment: What is this code trying to achieve? You've got a do loop with a for loop inside it with another for loop inside it. Your `Do While` condition is going to return True unless every single cell in column L is equal to 8. I can't see anything in your code that is setting every cell to 8. I can see you're also checking the length of the value is 8, which is different to checking the value is 8.

Comment: for example  i have cell value "12345678" in col 12 and then in col 13 and 14 i have cell value "abc", i want to clear content cell value in cold 12 and move cell value 13 to 12 and 14 to 13 thats it, my code running well but i dont know some time got error in 1 row

Comment: If you look at a row, can there be more values with 8 characters? Do you want to delete them, too? Why is 147 significant, do you have data up to column "FB"?

Answer (score 0):

### Move Cells

- For each row, this will delete the cell in column `L` if it is 8 characters long and shift the right-side data to the left repeatedly, until the cell contains a value with a different number of characters.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MoveCells()
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "L2"
    Const CHARS_LEN As Long = 8
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
    Dim lCell As Range
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set lCell = .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)
    End With
    If lCell.Row < fCell.Row Or lCell.Column < fCell.Column Then Exit Sub
    ' first cell is not part of the used range
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim rrg As Range, cell As Range, c As Long
    
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        Set cell = rrg.Cells(1)
        c = cCount
        Do While Len(CStr(cell.Value)) = CHARS_LEN
            cell.Delete xlShiftToLeft
            c = c - 1
            If c = 0 Then Exit Do
            Set cell = rrg.Cells(1)
        Loop
    Next rrg

End Sub
```